# Modularize Jupyter notebook preamble

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have a set of Jupyter notebooks, all of which need the same lines of code to initialize. The initialization contains:

- IPython magic commands (such as `%matplotlib inline` and `%load_ext autoreload`)
- importing modules
- configuring some settings, such as plot style

I am looking for a good way to put this code into a module that can be imported and ideally called with something like:

```
import preamble
preamble.run()
```

For the initialization code it is easy to do, but what about the module imports and magic commands?

Comment: You can make a module like you proposed. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may instead use a jupyter notebook for that.

Simply put all your code into preamble.ipynb and run it in your first cell with:

```
%run ./preamble.ipynb
```